# A good cloud solution for making Gantt charts

Tags: gantt

I am looking to make and maintain a Gantt chart, but I am unable to find any suitable solutions. It should be a cloud (meaning online) solution, so there can be several collaborators. It should also have normal features like linking tasks.

I have already tested a Gantt solution integrated in Google Spreadsheets, but it was too immature to be useful.

Comment: http://www.clockingit.com/ has support for GANTT charts, though I'm not sure how they are with multiple users and collaboration. I haven't used it extensively.

Comment: There is no way to make a good GANTT chart. The mere fact of the existence of one will basically guarantee your project will be over-time and over-budget.

Comment: +1 to @aclear16 for comedy. But also for basically being right...

Comment: Software recommendations...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ummm ... Did you try out Google Docs' Gantt chart making feature?
I recently used it for a project.

This tutorial on [Making a Gantt Chart with Google Docs](https://www.officetimeline.com/gantt-chart-google-docs) might help you.

Although there are better, quick and easy cloud products for making Gantt charts available on the Internet, I feel this feature of Google docs is much convenient to use as most of us are well-versed with Google Docs, as also for my project, the entire documentation was stored in Google Docs, which made things easy to manage.

Comment: The Google Spreadsheet plugin I had tried was a different one. Smartsheet seems to have all the features I need. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, real-time collaboration is not supported by Smartsheet, and even worse editing conflicts are not handled (changes are just overwritten), which means that this tool would be dangerous to use for more than a couple of persons.

Comment: This link is now broken.  Can yo update the answer, please?

Comment: @NewAlexandria Thanks for pointing out. The link is now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

A [Gantt Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) is an outcome of "Develop Schedule" process, which gets a list of Activities as an income. Thus, I would suggest you to try one of those tools that allow you to maintain a list of Activities online (with multiple collaborators) and then automatically generate a Gantt Chart from them. [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is one of the examples.

But if you still need a pure Gantt Chart drawing tool - consider [Gantter](http://gantter.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Having recently compared many online Gantt solutions, I can also recommend [Gantter.com](http://Gantter.com) as being one of the most polished and visually similar to MS Project.

It still has bugs and the interface is cramped in a single browser window, but enables printing and optional tight integration with Google Drive.

Possible security concerns if you install the optional app to Google Docs, which allows it to access any files in your Google Drive.

The background to my testing is that I was using JIRA OnDemand and could not integrate any Gantt generators with it.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [Wrike](http://www.wrike.com) – it has a good Gantt chart with ability to drag-and-drop tasks, create dependencies and milestones. The service is collaborative, so it enables you to share and edit tasks with other users. Besides, it has a number of useful features for task management, email and Google Drive integration, so you can manage all data in one place.

Answer (score 2):

I just spent a week comparing quite a few free online Gantt chart solutions.

I have not found anything that is visually similar to MS Project that is free.

I settled on free excel template that I converted to G doc (the "simple" one from this page https://exceltemplate.net/gantt-chart)

It's online on our google drive to allow for collaboration. Does the job but does not have all the bells and whistles online software would provide so if anyone did find a better ONLINE and FREE software, please chip in.